# jquery retrieve value inside textbox and put into php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, textbox

I need to get the value inside a textbox without refresh so i can execute an sql statement based on it.

Comment: how bout a code example? this should b very simple but im not gonna write it for u

Comment: In case you don't already know...this sounds like you're going to need some AJAX to make this happen. Take a look into that.

Comment: unless you use an ajax/jquery solution, you have to pass it through a form since php is server-side

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use the function `.val()`, then `.post()` to perform a HTTP post to a PHP page. You can then access the value from the PHP array `$_POST`.

Javascript is a client-side language, while PHP is server-sided. The variable can be passed using AJAX, which jQuery `.post()` is sufficient for.

```
//fetch the value of div "input"
var value = $(#'input').val();

//perform a HTTP post
$.post("dest_page.php", {
  input: value
});
```

Then access in PHP.

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
```

Answer (score 1):

A really super-easy way is to do a jQuery .load() on an event firing. This might be a button click or on .keyup() event.

```
$('#txtBox').keyup(function(){
    //COLLECT TXTBOX VALUE
    var value=$('#txtBox_selector').val()
    //SEND VALUE TO SERVER FOR ... WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH IT
    $('#your_selector').html('Loading...').load('path/to/script','value='+value);
})
```

Hope this helps.